# data type of param1 in function name({param1})

Tags: javascript, function, types

This might be simple to others but what's the data type of param1?

```
function name( {param1}, param2 ) {return;}
```

Comment: I think it's JSON Object

Comment: @Hkachhia [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) | [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2904131)

Comment: Please provide much more context here, it can be understood in many different ways.

Answer (score 0):

It is object destructuring

It is actually

```
function name( object1.param1, param2 ) {return;}
```

param1 is an property of an object.
Above function could be rewrite as :

```
function name( object1, param2 ) {let param1 = object1.param1}
```

Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 0):

- considering **param1** and param2,

param2 could **be anything**

but
definitely,

param 1 should be **any object**.

```
typeof({"dilshan"})  ----------------> Wrong
```

this will throw an error and **you can not do this**

```
typeof({"name":"dilshan"}) -----------> correct
```

this is valid one

then param1 should be an **object** :)